# jQuery based menu - How to make slideUp/Down run one after the other, not simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I got this jQuery based menu that whenever you already have a menu open and you click to open a different one, `slideUp` and `slideDown` run at the same time. It doesn't look good!

Is it possible to make `slideDown` wait for `slideUp`, so they don't overlap?

I guess it could be as simple as delaying `slideDown`'s start. However that should only happen when there's a menu already open that needs to be closed first. If nothing needs to be closed there shouldn't be any delay...

I don't know much about js so I don't know how complex this is or even if attainable at all.

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf7adn54/5/)

JS:

```
(function() {
  var __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
    __slice = [].slice;

  (function($, window) {
    var Tendina;
    Tendina = (function() {
      Tendina.prototype.defaults = {
        animate: true,
        speed: 500,
        onHover: false,
        hoverDelay: 200,
        activeMenu: null
      };

      function Tendina(el, options) {
        this._eventHandler = __bind(this._eventHandler, this);
        this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.elSelector = this._getSelector(this.$el);
        this.$el.addClass('tendina');
        this.linkSelector = "" + this.elSelector + " a";
        this.$listElements = $(this.linkSelector).parent('li');
        this._hideSubmenus();
        this.mouseEvent = this.options.onHover === true ? 'mouseenter.tendina' : 'click.tendina';
        this._bindEvents();
        if (this.options.activeMenu !== null) {
          this._openActiveMenu(this.options.activeMenu);
        }
      }

      Tendina.prototype._bindEvents = function() {
        return $(document).on(this.mouseEvent, this.linkSelector, this._eventHandler);
      };

      Tendina.prototype._unbindEvents = function() {
        return $(document).off(this.mouseEvent);
      };

      Tendina.prototype._getSelector = function(el) {
        var elId, firstClass, _ref;
        firstClass = (_ref = $(el).attr('class')) != null ? _ref.split(' ')[0] : void 0;
        elId = $(el).attr('id');
        if (elId !== void 0) {
          return "#" + elId;
        } else {
          return "." + firstClass;
        }
      };

      Tendina.prototype._isFirstLevel = function(targetEl) {
        if ($(targetEl).parent().parent().hasClass('tendina')) {
          return true;
        }
      };

      Tendina.prototype._eventHandler = function(event) {
        var targetEl;
        targetEl = event.currentTarget;
        if (this._hasChildrenAndIsHidden(targetEl)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (this.options.onHover) {
            return setTimeout((function(_this) {
              return function() {
                if ($(targetEl).is(':hover')) {
                  return _this._openSubmenu(targetEl);
                }
              };
            })(this), this.options.hoverDelay);
          } else {
            return this._openSubmenu(targetEl);
          }
        } else if (this._isCurrentlyOpen(targetEl)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (!this.options.onHover) {
        return this._closeSubmenu(targetEl);
      }
    }
  };

  Tendina.prototype._openSubmenu = function(el) {
    var $openMenus, $targetMenu;
    $targetMenu = $(el).next('ul');
    $openMenus = this.$el.find('> .selected ul').not($targetMenu).not($targetMenu.parents('ul'));
    $(el).parent('li').addClass('selected');
    this._close($openMenus);
    this.$el.find('.selected').not($targetMenu.parents('li')).removeClass('selected');
    this._open($targetMenu);
    if (this.options.openCallback) {
      return this.options.openCallback($(el).parent());
    }
  };

  Tendina.prototype._closeSubmenu = function(el) {
    var $nestedMenus, $targetMenu;
    $targetMenu = $(el).next('ul');
    $nestedMenus = $targetMenu.find('li.selected');
    $(el).parent().removeClass('selected');
    this._close($targetMenu);
    $nestedMenus.removeClass('selected');
    this._close($nestedMenus.find('ul'));
    if (this.options.closeCallback) {
      return this.options.closeCallback($(el).parent());
    }
  };

  Tendina.prototype._open = function($el) {
    if (this.options.animate) {
      return $el.stop(true, true).slideDown(this.options.speed);
    } else {
      return $el.show();
    }
  };

  Tendina.prototype._close = function($el) {
    if (this.options.animate) {
      return $el.stop(true, true).slideUp(this.options.speed);
    } else {
      return $el.hide();
    }
  };

  Tendina.prototype._hasChildrenAndIsHidden = function(el) {
    return $(el).next('ul').length > 0 && $(el).next('ul').is(':hidden');
  };

  Tendina.prototype._isCurrentlyOpen = function(el) {
    return $(el).parent().hasClass('selected');
  };

  Tendina.prototype._hideSubmenus = function() {
    return this.$el.find('ul').hide();
  };

  Tendina.prototype._showSubmenus = function() {
    this.$el.find('ul').show();
    return this.$el.find('li').addClass('selected');
  };

  Tendina.prototype._openActiveMenu = function(element) {
    var $activeMenu, $activeParents;
    $activeMenu = element instanceof jQuery ? element : this.$el.find(element);
    $activeParents = $activeMenu.closest('ul').parents('li').find('> a');
    if (this._hasChildrenAndIsHidden($activeParents)) {
      $activeParents.next('ul').show();
    } else {
      $activeMenu.next('ul').show();
    }
    $activeMenu.parent().addClass('selected');
    return $activeParents.parent().addClass('selected');
  };

  Tendina.prototype.destroy = function() {
    this.$el.removeData('tendina');
    this._unbindEvents();
    this._showSubmenus();
    this.$el.removeClass('tendina');
    return this.$el.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  };

  Tendina.prototype.hideAll = function() {
    return this._hideSubmenus();
  };

  Tendina.prototype.showAll = function() {
    return this._showSubmenus();
  };

  return Tendina;

})();
return $.fn.extend({
  tendina: function() {
    var args, option;
    option = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this, data;
      $this = $(this);
      data = $this.data('tendina');
      if (!data) {
        $this.data('tendina', (data = new Tendina(this, option)));
      }
      if (typeof option === 'string') {
        return data[option].apply(data, args);
      }
    });
  }
});
  })(window.jQuery, window);

}).call(this);


$('.dropdown').tendina({
        // This is a setup made only
        // to show which options you can use,
        // it doesn't actually make sense!
        animate: true,
        speed: 500,
        onHover: false,
        hoverDelay: 300,
        activeMenu: $('#deepest'),
        openCallback: function(clickedEl) {
          console.log('Hey dude!');
        },
        closeCallback: function(clickedEl) {
          console.log('Bye dude!');
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
$(".something").slideUp(500, function(){

   // Callback, will work after 500ms of above animation will complete.
   $(".somethingother").slideDown(500);

});
```

Your jsfiddle js code was very messy, so i couldn't tweak with that.

Comment: How could that work? Are you sure you understood what I'm trying to fix? slideUp/Down works great... I'm just trying to delay slideDown when there's already a menu open and slideUp needs to run first. Currently they're running simultaneously... That's the issue!

Comment: Sorry, I unintentionally used the minified version. Here's a fiddle with the proper one: http://jsfiddle.net/vf7adn54/7/ easy to understand.

Comment: Yes the above code will do `$(".somethingother").slideDown(500)` when `$(".something").slideUp(500)` completes the slideUp effect.

Comment: Would you mind adding it to this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vf7adn54/7/ ? I'm self-taught in js and not really sure how to approach it... Thanks.

Comment: Actually your jsfiddle JS does not have slideUp or slideDown anywhere. If it has can you please point me the line no.

Comment: slideDown (116) slideUp (124)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71046/discussion-between-void-and-cheng-zhaa).